# NullPointerException in TextInputLayout on Xiaomi with Android 10

Tags: java, android, exception, android-10.0, xiaomi

I recently started using `TextInputLayout` in my android app. After that, strange `NullPointerException` errors started to appear. These errors only occur on `Xiaomi` devices with `Androind 10`.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke direct method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.initDrawables()' on a null object reference
android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.access$300
```

There is no way to reproduce the error (I do not have a Xiaomi device). Searching the Internet realized that this error occurs when trying to enter email in the `TextInputLayout` field.

There is a solution for React Native on the internet: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27204

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a solution for Java.

**Screenshot from Crashlytics:**

[image: Crashlytics]

**Full report:**

```
android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.access$300 (Editor.java:6709)
android.widget.Editor.getEmailPopupWindow (Editor.java:1471)
android.widget.Editor.showEmailPopupWindow (Editor.java:1479)
android.widget.Editor.handleEmailPopup (Editor.java:1458)
android.widget.Editor.updateCursorPosition (Editor.java:2101)
android.widget.TextView.getUpdatedHighlightPath (TextView.java:7823)
android.widget.TextView.onDraw (TextView.java:8008)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:21594)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20437)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:21312)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4472)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4231)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:21601)
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.draw (TextInputLayout.java:3064)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20437)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4456)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4429)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20388)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2955)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1865)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8029)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:969)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:793)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:728)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:954)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7509)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Comment: Facing this same issue

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to fix the crash. It will disable the cursor when editing an email address, but it will not crash.

```
if (android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Xiaomi", ignoreCase = true) &&
    android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    editText.isCursorVisible = false
}
```